# Best way to store data like restaurant checkin count?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a page that shows restaurant profile data, and one of the data shown is the total checkin count of users to the restaurant

I have a mysql table like: `user_checkins` which stores the checkin of users into restaurants like:

```
id | user_id | res_id | checkin_date        |
 1 |     102 | 5526   | 2016-04-21 03:20:21 |
 2 |     165 | 5574   | 2016-04-21 06:35:21 |
 3 |     102 | 4565   | 2016-04-24 02:15:30 |
```

and another table `res_checkin_count`:

```
id | res_id | total_checkin_count |
 1 |   5526 | 1055                |
```

after a while many rows will be created in `user_checkins`, because people checkin frequently

Question : Should I delete the older rows? like create a cronjob that deletes old rows periodically(like daily) for reach restaurant and update the restaurant `total_checkin_count` number in another mysql TABLE storing only the `total_checkin_count` of each restaurant? will this consume alot of memory?

or

I keep the rows and let it accumulate and use `SELECT COUNT(*)` all to get each restaurant `total_checkin_count`?

EDIT: the `user_checkins` table actually stores all user checkin for various restaurants, everytime someone visits a 'restaurant_profile' webpage, the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query will run on the `user_checkins` table for `res_id` x, to get the `total checkin count` of that restaurant, is that redundant?

Comment: Why not just have a running total per location and a last checkin column in a singular table? Do you really need to know exactly when they checked in? If so, can you archive it?

Comment: Everytime when someone visits a restaurant_profile webpage, I will run the SELECT COUNT(*) for the user_checkins table (which store checkins for all restaurants), so means everytime someone visit a restaurant_profile webpage, the SELECT COUNT(*) will run on that table, is that redundant?

Answer (score 0):

When you say many rows you need to assess if many is beyond the capabilities of MySQL. In general MySQL should easily be able to handle in the order of 100 million rows per table. Are you expecting to exceed over 100 million rows any time soon? If not, then leave your data alone, it reduces the complexity that would come with an archiving system.

If on the other hand you are expecting more than hundreds of millions of rows on tables, then yes, running a daily job to delete or archive your data can be helpful in keeping your database running well.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me  those tables are in MySQL, however I'll just get rid of res_checkin_count is a duplicate of an aggregate function that is the COUNT so you are wasting memory, so there can only be 2 scenarios:

1 your user_checkins table does not have more than 2 million records and you create nuncluster index for Column res_id and will be fine.

2 You have a Monstrous website where you store more than 2 million active records and you create tables per State or per brick (3 to 5 zipcodes) that way you will have distributed records most likely people form TX will search and Query restaurants from TX and so on.

Comment: What? 2 millions? If you meant 2 billions as max INT it can go up to 4 billions+ using unsigned int.

Comment: I don't mean the max number that Index can hold with a INT I mean that if he is using a host provider some times MySQL databases are limited to 2 GB per table. I gave a recommendation to balance table load not balance server work load.